# Waiting for error from apns with enhanced format in php

Tags: php, stream, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We're using a modified version of [easy-apns](http://www.easyapns.com/) for sending our push messages. With the enhanced push message format the apple server responds if an error occurs, and does nothing if everything goes well.

The problem is that we have to wait for an error a certain amount of time after each message has been sent. For example if we receive no response after 1 second, we assume everything went ok.

With 20000 push messages, this takes far too long. Is there any way I can listen for errors in a faster way? For example sending to 1000 devices and then listen for errors? What happens if the connection gets closed, can I still read the error response?

Ideal would be some kind of asynchronous writing and reading, but I think that's not possible.

Here's the corresponding code:

```
    $fp = $this->connect();

    $expiry = time()+60*60;

    // construct message
    $msg = chr(1).pack("N",$batchid).pack("N",$expiry).pack("n",32).pack('H*',$devicetoken).pack("n",strlen($payload)).$payload;

    // send message to Apple
    $fwrite = fwrite($fp, $msg);

    if(!$fwrite) {
        // connection has been closed
        $this->disconnect();
        throw new Exception("Connection closed");

    } else {
        // read response from Apple

        // Timeout. 1 million micro seconds = 1 second
        $tv_sec = 1;
        $tv_usec = 0;

        $r = array($fp);
        $we = null; // Temporaries. "Only variables can be passed as reference."

        // PROBLEM: this method waits for $tv_sec seconds for a response
        $numChanged = stream_select($r, $we, $we, $tv_sec, $tv_usec);

        if( $numChanged === false ) {
            throw new Exception("Failed selecting stream to read.");
        } elseif ( $numChanged > 0 ) {

            $command = ord( fread($fp, 1) );
            $status = ord( fread($fp, 1) );
            $identifier = implode('', unpack("N", fread($fp, 4)));

            if( $status > 0 ) {

                // The socket has also been closed. Cause reopening in the loop outside.
                $this->disconnect();
                throw new MessageException("APNS responded with status $status: {$this->statusDesc[$status]} ($devicetoken).".microtime(), $status);

            } else {
                // unknown response, assume ok
            }

        } else {
            // no response, assume ok
        }
    }
```